# UILabel not allocated, is null - why?

Tags: uilabel

I have created UIView which has UITableView and UILabel in the interface builder. They are connected to IBOutlets to the corresponding UIView class.

In UIView class i have implemented UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate.Those delegate works fine when those methods are called.

But, When I try to update the UILabel in the "viewDidLoad" method, nothing happens because the UILabel isn't getting created - the debugger shows a value of x0.

What the problem here? and what i need to do for UILabel to get created?

Comment: are you stating the property of the UILable in the .h file and synthesizing it later in the .m file.

Comment: Yes. The problem is fixed now, although I'm not sure exactly why. I decided to go with the tableHeader property instead of the label, and used some sample code from this url: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html. However, I left the label in, and sure enough it is displaying the updated text as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your table view can be seen that that means your xib file loads correctly. The only thing that I can think of is that you did not have a connection to the UILabel in the interface builder, I would suggest you to check and reconnect it.